# Como transformar um array de uma dimensão em duas em Java?

Tags: java, array

Tenho um array de inteiros unidimensional, assim:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
```

E quero transformá-lo em um array de duas dimensões, por exemplo:

```
[1, 2, 3],

[4, 5, 6],

[7, 8, 9],

[10, 11, 12]
```

Como faço esta transformação, em Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note que existem várias maneiras de transformar um array unidimensional em um array bidimensional. Veja algumas representações alternativas do exemplo:

```
[1, 2],           [1, 2, 3, 4],            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],

[3, 4],           [5, 6, 7, 8],            [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

[5, 6],           [9, 10, 11, 12]

[7, 8],

[9, 10],

[11, 12]
```

São exemplos que representam matrizes 6x2, 3x4 e 2x6, respectivamente. Logo, é necessário saber a largura do array, e a altura pode ser calculada a partir daí, sabendo o tamanho do array unidimensional.

```
static int[][] dimensionar_uma_em_duas (int[] matriz, int largura) {
      int altura = matriz.length / largura;
      int[][] ret = new int[altura][largura];
      for(int i=0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
            ret[i/largura][i%largura] = matriz[i];
      }
      return ret;
}
```

O método **dimensionar_uma_em_duas**, obtém a altura do array dividindo o tamanho total dele pela largura, que é um parâmetro de entrada. A partir daí ele percorre o vetor unidimensional de uma vez, utilizando as funções de divisão inteira e módulo para posicionar corretamente os elementos no novo vetor bidimensional.

Para um vetor com altura 4 e largura 3, e a entrada do primeiro exemplo, os cálculos (i/largura) e (i%largura) retornarão as posições: 0, 0; 0,1; 0,2; 1,0; 1,1; 1,2; 2,0; 2,1; 2,2; 3,0; 3,1 e 3,2; respectivamente.