# Rotacionar uma imagem que esta em um array

Tags: java, imagem

Boa tarde, eu tenho uma imagem colorida em um array 1D, por exemplo:

```
int[] image = {255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 0};
```

Este array possui 6 pixels, vermelho, verde, azul, azul, verde, vermelho, imaginando que estes pixels estão posicionados de forma horizontal:

```
| Vermelho | Verde | Azul     |
| Azul     | Verde | Vermelho |
```

De qual forma eu poderia rotacionar esta imagem para que a disposição dos pixels se torne vertical:

```
| Azul     | Vermelho |
| Verde    | Verde    |
| Vermelho | Azul     |
```

Desejo colocar este array rotacionado em outro array 1D.

Comment: A diferença é. Apenas na hora de obter ou imprimir os valores, o array continua da mesma forma

Comment: Você quer distribuir cada grupo de cores em indices com 3 de diferença, é isso?

Comment: Desculpe, talvez eu tenha me expressado, mal, preciso inserir essa nova imagem em um novo array 1D, para uma imagem que contenha apenas 3 pixels realmente só irá se alterar na parte de salvar o arquivo, porém quando envolve mais linhas, ai é necessário alterar estes dados. Melhorei o exemplo, talvez fique mais claro. Abrass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você for trabalhar com o array unidimensional, então não existe esse conceito de horizontal ou vertical. O que você pode fazer é substituir a posição das cores.

Mas se você quiser transformar o array em um bidimensional, então sugiro ler as respostas dessas duas perguntas que vão te ajudar bastante:

- [Como transformar um array de uma dimensão em duas em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188456/como-transformar-um-array-de-uma-dimens%C3%A3o-em-duas-em-java/188457#188457)
- [Como rotacionar uma matriz (array) em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188629/como-rotacionar-uma-matriz-array-em-java)

É possível fazer a rotação das cores em um array bidimensional e depois converter de volta para um unidimensional.

Comment: Andei dando uma olhada, porém cheguei a conclusão que não se aplica ao meu problema, pois o array que possuo representa cores RGB, eu teria que transformar isto em um array 3D, creio eu.

Comment: Finalmente consegui, realmente esta era a solução, transformar em um array 2D para então rotacionar, funciona até mesmo com imagens coloridas, obrigado.